# How to output a pdf417 object as a barcode image using tcpdf class php?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I was able to create a pdf417 object using pdf417 class from tcpdf. But I am not sure which way to go for getting a image based output for the above said object using tcpdf class php.

Answer (score 0):

I was moving in the wrong direction used the code from example50.php in tcpdf for this issue and resolved it.